# How do you extract from a binary file created with Ant <concat>?

Tags: ant, concatenation

I have a binary file that was created with the Ant <concat> task:

```
<target name="bun.create">
    <concat destfile="final.bun" binary="yes">
        <filelist dir="scripts/" files="script.sh"/>
        <filelist dir="working/" files="files.tgz"/>
    </concat>
    <chmod file="final.bun" perm="+x"/>
</target>
```

I have the final.bun file and am wondering how I can extract the script.sh and files.tgz from it, without executing it?  I know the unzip command doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do this - at least not easily. I'm sure there are some old Unis heads who can use the [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) utility to do this, but that is still a hack. What you have done is create a file format that doesn't really exist. It's like concating together a Word document with an Excel document.

In fact, I'm not even sure if the `<concat>` task wouldn't shred the binary file into an incomprehensible mess as it was trying to concatenate it.

If you must put both files together, use the `<zip/>`, or `<tar/>` task to combine both files together. Yes, I know that `files.tgz` is already a compressed archive, but this would be the best way to put those two files together.